# Can I access which animation is playing from within a blend tree?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can I access which animation is playing from within a blend tree? I have a animator where run, stand, and attack are all controlled with a blend tree. All the blend trees have 8 sets of sprite animations all set out in the same order which correlate to 8 directions: up is in the first slot, top right in the second, etc.
[image]
[image]

For the attacking, I want the hurt box to appear based on the animation direction so there is some connection to what the player sees. However, I'm having issues getting the actual animation that is playing from within the blend tree. Can I access which animation that is playing from within the blend tree? Preferably, I would want to get the index of the animation that is playing so it would work for all my blend trees instead of hard coding animation names.

If reading the blend tree animation name/index is not possible, is there a way to emulate how the animator figures out which animation to play through c# code? That way I could just do the calculation for where the hurt box will appear myself.

Comment: Well afaik it is called `BlendTree` because it *blends* over between multiple animations .. so there is always multiple possible animations running at the same time and they are blender together ... The calculations here is quite simply: horizontal=1, vertical=1 results in fully top-right corner, horizontal=0, vertical=0 results in the center so a blend between all animations (assuming it results in an idle state)

Comment: I'm using sprite animation so there isn't any actual blending. I also can't do binary calculation as the blend tree will treat (0.14, 0) as (1,0) and (0.6,0.2) as (1,1). Is there documentation on how unity treats the thresholds?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Decided to just put an animation event in the animation that would currently be playing and on it's start, update in code. Might not be the best but it works.